# python read contents of encrypted(using gnupg) zipfile without decrypting the file to filesystem

Tags: python, gnupg

With the help of zipfile.ZipFile, I'm able to access/read files inside zip file without actually extracting to a folder.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('data.zip', 'rb') as zfile:
    with zfile.open('fil.dat', 'r') as dfile:
        csv_data = io.TextIOWrapper(dfile, encoding='utf-8')
        ....
        ....
```

Now, Is it possible to read/access files inside an encrypted zip file? The zip file is encrypted using `gnupg`
I have a workaround to decrypt and read the contents of zip, like below

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
with open('key.asc') as kfile:
    key = kfile.read()

gpg.import_keys(key)
with open('data.zip.gpg', 'rb') as gfile:
    gpg.decrypt_file(gfile, passphrase='password', output='data.zip')
```

This will create a new decrypted zip file on the filesystem, allowing me read/access files inside zip file and have to delete the file after every use.
**Is it possible to decrypt the zip file to a file-like object and access the contents without actually creating decrypted zip file on filesystem?**

I tried something like below, but failed.

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
with open('key.asc') as kfile:
    key = kfile.read()
gpg.import_keys(key)

zip_file_obj = io.BytesIO()

with open('data.zip.gpg', 'rb') as gfile:
    gpg.decrypt_file(gfile, passphrase='password', output=zip_file_obj)
```

The above code fails with error BytesIO type is not a valid input.
**Is there a way to accomplish this or any other python wrapper/package for my use case?**

 *Note: I'm working with python 3.6*

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gptester.py", line 15, in <module>
    gpg.decrypt_file(gfile, passphrase='TESTTESTTEST', output=zip_file_obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnupg/gnupg.py", line 1093, in decrypt_file
    if os.path.exists(output):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.BytesIO
```

**EDIT - II**

I tried this code from the suggestions provided

```
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
import gnupg

with open('worker/key.asc') as kfile:
    key = kfile.read()

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
gpg.import_keys(key)
zip_file_obj = BytesIO()

with open('data.zip.gpg', 'rb') as gfile:
    decrypt_data = gpg.decrypt_file(gfile, passphrase='password')

zip_file_obj = BytesIO(decrypt_data)
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnupg/_meta.py", line 650, in _read_response
    result._handle_status(keyword, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gnupg/_parsers.py", line 1294, in _handle_status
    raise ValueError("Unknown status message: %r" % key)
ValueError: Unknown status message: 'PINENTRY_LAUNCHED'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gptester.py", line 17, in <module>
    zip_file_obj = BytesIO(decrypt_data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Crypt'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#decryption) shows that you can do `decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(stream)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#decryption) shows that you can do

```
decrypted_data = gpg.decrypt_file(gfile, passphrase='password')
```

to get it without writing to file.

To create file-like object you need `decrypted_data.data` and

```
zip_file_obj = io.BytesIO(decrypted_data.data)
```

Documentation mentions also `str(decrypted_data)` as method to get data.

Comment: Per documentation, gfile is a file-like object for encrypted file but not a file-like object for decryption. My ask is different, I'm looking to access contents of an encrypted zip file with a file-like object or temporary file object without actually keeping the decrypted version of the file on a filesystem.

Comment: I don't know if I understand but you have your data in `decrypted_data` and you can use `io.BytesIO(decrypted_data)` to have it as file-like object.

Comment: From your code, it looks like status message is being returned by gpg.decrypt_file and hence decrypted_data is not having the file data. I get error after trying your suggestion, check EDIT-II in question for code and error

Comment: documentation shows `str(decrypted_data)` to get data. I found also `decrypted_data.data` which probably maybe gives data. But I don't have files to test it.

Comment: Thank you, very much. I was able to create BytesIO object using decrypted_data.data and then I was able to link my pipeline to this. If possible, to help other readers you may edit the answer to make it much finer.